Loop through column and insert rows after duplicated values
I need to write a macro which will add an empty row after duplicated values (there could me more that two duplicated values).
Once I starting the code it runs and never ends. I'm not sure what should I change here to get this right. So far, I tried such macro, but it stuck in do while loop.
Sub dup()
    Dim rw As Long
    Dim val1, val2 As String
    Sheets(4).Activate
    Range("C3").Select

    For rw = 3 To Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        val1 = Range("C" & rw).Value
        val2 = Range("C" & rw + 1).Value
        Do While IsNull(Range("C" & rw)) = False
            If val2 = val1 Then
                Rows(rw + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
            Else
                If val1 = val2 Then
                End If
            End If
        Loop
    Next
End Sub


You need to use a reverse loop. Also avoid the use of .Select/.Activate. You may want to see How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA.
Work with the objects directly. Is this what you are trying (Untested)?
Option Explicit

Sub dup()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    '~~> Set this to the relevant worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4")

    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    
    With ws
        '~~> Find last row in Column C
        lRow = .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
        '~~> Reverse Loop
        For i = lRow To 3 Step -1
            '~~> Check for duplicate. If found, insert row
            If .Range("C" & i).Value = .Range("C" & i - 1).Value Then .Rows(i).Insert
        Next i
    End With
End Sub


Hi, it does not work the way I would like to. This macro adds empty row between duplicated values, not below. Another thing is that if there are more than 3 cells with same value it adds a row twice instead of omitting those.
Regarding .Select/.Activate thank you for this tip, I'm at the beggining of my learning process :)

Can you post a screenshot of how your data looks like and how it should look like after the macro is run.

Screenshot added to original post. I have a list of employees and I need to calculate KPI of their performance. Each employee can be responsible for several products, so I need to sum up all values for each person - to do that I wanted to add empty row under each duplicates (after sorting ofc) and to add formulas.
